# How can I use ng-bind-html as an element?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

For an Angular 1.2 project, I'd like to render a subset of `<td>`s inside of a table row using `ng-bind-html` in order to reduce the number of watchers.  I cannot easily render all `<td>`s this way because some of them have `ng-click`s, `ng-if`'s and `ng-class`es attached to them.

Currently the `ng-bind-html` element is rendered as td children elements of the `<td>` that it's called in.  However, `ng-bind-html` cannot be called as an element (must be an attribute).

Any ideas on how to approach this? (I've been looking at some jquery but I'm pretty new to that area).

```
<tr>
    <td><span>{{entry.name}}</span></td>
    <td ng-bind-html="generateStaticHtmlColumns(entry.data)"></td>
    <td>{{entry.address | number}}</td>
    <td ng-if='!entry.loading' tooltip position="bottom">{{entry.phone | number}}</td>
</tr>
```

Essentially, I'd like the `<td>` calling using `ng-bind-html` to be replaced with the "td"s it's returning rather than appending them as children.

Comment: For the record, I decided this isn't currently possible.  I ended up rendering the whole table in the JS, using `ng-bind-html` to show it, and attaching jquery events on certain user actions.  If you need to include a directive in your table (I needed to for a loading icon), you can `$compile` and use jquery again to put in in the DOM after the digest cycle completes (using `$timeout`), like: `$("tr#my-row-id").replaceWith($compile(angularRowDirective)($scope));`  I'm actually pretty happy with the flexibility and performance improvements this has provided.

Comment: what do you mean by reduce the number of watchers?